# NPM и deploy по ftp

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Всем доброго времени суток! Делаю веб-приложение на Angular 2. Захотелось автоматизировать deploy по ftp. Для сборки использую Webpack. Есть информация, что сам node.js может помочь в решении задачи, пример скрипта есть. Но как заставить выполняться нужный скрипт после выполнения команды npm run build ? Как я понимаю, надо добавлять вызов скрипта в секцию scripts файла package.json. Или я неправ ?
Секция scripts файла package.json.

```
"scripts": {
"clean": "rimraf node_modules doc dist && npm cache clean",
"clean-install": "npm run clean && npm install",
"clean-start": "npm run clean-install && npm start",
"watch": "webpack --watch --progress --profile",
"build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
"server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
"webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
"webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
"lint": "tslint --force \"src/**/*.ts\"",
"e2e": "protractor",
"e2e-live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
"pretest": "npm run lint",
"test": "karma start",
"posttest": "remap-istanbul -i coverage/json/coverage-final.json -o coverage/html -t html",
"test-watch": "karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch",
"ci": "npm run e2e && npm run test",
"docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json src/app/app.component.ts",
"start": "npm run server",
"start:hmr": "npm run server -- --hot",
"postinstall": "npm run webdriver-update",
 },
```

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас *уже есть скрипт для деплоя*, то вы можете добавить для него отдельную запись в `scripts`, а так же создать объединенную команду для последовательной сборки и выгрузки проекта:

```
"scripts": {
   "deploy": "<здесь вы вызываете CLI команду для выгрузки готового приложения>",
   "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
   "build-n-deploy": "npm run build && npm run deploy"
},
```

Вот пример билда с деплоем:

```
npm run build-n-deploy
```

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо из помощь, в общем-то Ваш совет и сработал - создали Node-модуль фтп-деплоя и его подцепили к команде сборки. Все оказалось просто. Просто еще были мысли о варианте через Git-хук, но в моих условиях проекта это бы не сработало в итоге. Ради последнего пришлось изучать Git, а это оказывается целый мир :-)

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас git. Можно установить глобально допустим  [npm git-pull-all](https://github.com/tatsuyaoiw/git-pull-all).

а в `package.json` в скрипт добавить что то вроде этого:

```
"scripts": {
 ...

 git_pull:'git-pull-all ./'
}
```

Потому `npm install` и по идее должно сработать выливание по всем веткам и папкам